# netrw expand folders - strange behaviour

Tags: netrw

I'm getting very strange behaviour when I try to expand the listing of a folder by pressing enter. Take the following screenshot

[image]

Currently, I have file `2.1` open. But when I press `Enter` on `1/` to expand it, `2/` first closes and then I have to press `Enter` again to finally expand `1/`.

Is there a way to avoid this so that `2/` never closes in the first place?

Edit: Here are my netrw settings

```
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_altv = 1
let g:netrw_winsize = -28
let g:netrw_banner = 0
```

Comment: Any chance this issue is related to `:h netrw-s-cr`?

Comment: Not sure. I've updated my post with my netrw settings

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce it. But from `:h netrw-s-cr`: *When the tree listing style is enabled (see |netrw-i|) and one is using
gvim, then the <s-cr> mapping may be used to squeeze (close) the
directory currently containing the cursor.*

Comment: I'm only hitting <cr>, not <s-cr> and the problem persists even on terminal vim.

Comment: Ok. My doubt was actually what would happen if pressing `<s-cr>` (if it had worked, a simple remap would be a workaround). Have you tried `vim -u NONE -N`? Or maybe even some binary search: https://github.com/mhinz/vim-galore#general-tips ?

Comment: pressing <s-cr> does not work apparently, it says keymap not defined. I'll tr reproducing with your method.